# Text-analysis: Import CSV without stringquotes

Tags: string-manipulation, text, csv-format

I have a large amount of text-files.  I want to compare these text-files based on common 'words'. I export the output of my analysis as a CSV file. When I import the same file I get all seperate words with String Quotes.

As a example I use two text files from Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama

> Obama = {"Barack Hussein Obama II (born August 4,1961) served as the
>   44th President of the United States from 2009 to 2017. ......be built
>   in Chicago."};

```
Obama1 = Select[
   Flatten[StringCases[ToLowerCase[Obama], 
     RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]], 
   StringLength[#] > 2 &];

Obama2 = Sort[
  Select[Tally[Flatten[Obama1]], #[[2]] > 2 &], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton

> clinton = {"William Jefferson Clinton.....Clinton Bush Haiti Fund."};

```
clinton1 = 
  Select[Flatten[
    StringCases[ToLowerCase[clinton], 
     RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]], 
   StringLength[#] > 2 &];

clinton2 = 
 Sort[Select[
   Tally[Flatten[clinton1]], #[[2]] > 2 &], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]
```

In this example I have two datasets. Now I combine them and select the words both textsfiles have in common:

```
nw = Join[Obama2, clinton2];
nw1 = Gather[nw, First[#1] == First[#2] &];
nw2 = Map[{#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, -1]]], Length[#[[All, -1]]]} &, 
    nw1] // N;
nw3 = Select[nw2, #[[3]] == 2 &][[All, {1, 2}]];
naam5 = {};
AppendTo[naam5, Prepend[nw3, {"clinton", "Obama"}]]
```

Because I have many textfiles, the analysis-file must have the next structure:

{{name1, name2}, {{word1, word2,.....}},
({name2, name3}, {{word1, word3, word4...}}

```
Export["test1.csv", naam5, "CSV"];
```

When I open the file in a text-editor, I get this:

"{""clinton"", ""Obama""}","{""the"", 39.}","{""and"", 20.5}","{""his"", 7.}","{""was"", 7.5}","{""from"", 6.5}","{""act"", 4.5}","{""for"", 5.}","{""american"", 3.}","{""first"", 3.5}","{""president"", 4.}"

When I open the dataset in a Notebook

```
data = Import[test1.csv"]
```

The result in my notebook is:
{{"{"clinton", "Obama"}", "{"the", 39.}", "{"and", 20.5}", 
  "{"his", 7.}", "{"was", 7.5}", "{"from", 6.5}", 
  "{"act", 4.5}", "{"for", 5.}", "{"american", 3.}", 
  "{"first", 3.5}", "{"president", 4.}"},

I want to get the same result without the string quotes. Who has a suggestion?

Comment: If the string quotes were removed, they'll be treated as symbols by Mathematica, which I think is risky. Aside from your question, I feel you may rethink the way in analysing your data.

Comment: why have you selected csv format for this?

Comment: Try this:  `naam5 === ToExpression[ data ]`.  I think you will find they are identical.